# Checking for overlaps in polygons using Oracle Spatial?

Tags: overlapping-features, oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

I want to get a list of all the polygons from table 2 which overlap with one polygon from table 1. Following is the query which I am trying to use which doesnt give any result.

```
 Select b.bg_id
 from table1 a,table2 b
 where a.store_id = '74073'
 AND SDO_Relate(a.geometry,b.geometry,'mask=anyinteract')='TRUE';
```

What would be wrong here?

Comment: try it without the line: where a.store_id = '74073'   Do you still get no results?

Comment: Try without where clause and check if select b.bg_id from table1 where store_id = '74073'  giving you any row?